# Merge line-break-related tags

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, synonym-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tag synonyms for [linebreak]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111538/tag-synonyms-for-linebreak)

On Stack Overflow, we have

[linebreak](/questions/tagged/linebreak): **68** questions
[linebreaks](/questions/tagged/linebreaks): **187** questions
[line-break](/questions/tagged/line-break): **21** questions
[line-breaks](/questions/tagged/line-breaks): **20** questions

Can these all be merged into one big happy synonym relationship? It'll probably be easier to do them all at once via mod powers than to wait for the few users who have the requisite tag scores to band together and create all three synonyms.

Comment: [Yes, please |:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126509/how-can-i-detect-an-incoming-line-break-in-uitextview)